# CMake escaping issue: it escapes spaces in my add_custom_target COMMAND, but doesn't escape '('

Tags: cmake

Consider the following snippet:

```
set(CODESIGN_CERT $ENV{CODESIGN_CERT}) # contains "My Name (My Team ID)"
add_custom_target(make-package ALL
    command1
    COMMAND command2
    COMMAND codesign ... --sign "${CODESIGN_CERT}" ...
)
```

when it comes to executing the command, it fails with (showing with VERBOSE output):

```
cd /path/to/build/dir && codesign ... --sign My\ Name\ (My\ Team\ ID) ...
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `cd /path/to/build/dir && codesign ... --sign My\ Name\ (My\ Team\ ID) ...'
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/make-package] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/make-package.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

so it looked like CMake has tried to escape special chars, because the spaces became `\` , but it didn't escape `(`/`)`, and the shell interpreter doesn't like that.

Now if I try for instance to quote the argument myself:

```
    COMMAND codesign ... --sign \"${CODESIGN_CERT}\" ...
```

the argument next to `--sign` passed to the `codesign` program becomes literally `My\ Name\ (My\ Team\ ID)` (i.e. it contains backslashes), and it won't be recognized.

How can this issue be solved?

Also passing `"\"${CODESIGN_CERT}\""` or `\""${CODESIGN_CERT}"\"` doesn't work, because of similar reasons.

Comment: Have you tried to add `VERBATIM` option for `add_custom_target`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `VERBATIM` flag for `add_custom_target`. From [the docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html):

> All arguments to the commands will be escaped properly for the build tool so that the invoked command receives each argument unchanged. Note that one level of escapes is still used by the CMake language processor before add_custom_target even sees the arguments. Use of `VERBATIM` is recommended as it enables correct behavior. When `VERBATIM` is not given the behavior is platform specific because there is no protection of tool-specific special characters.